# C# EF Core Web API Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So my problem is simple. I have Users and Workspaces. A user can have many workspaces and workspaces can have many users. However, the problem comes when I want to add in a fourth party.

I want to check if the user is in the correct workspace before the user can get/post/put/delete.
I used to do this by doing a simple check like this:

```
 var workspace = _workspaceService.GetById(User.WorkspaceId);

    private Workspace getWorkspace(int id)
    {
        var workspace = _context.Workspace.Find(id);
        if (workspace == null) throw new KeyNotFoundException("Workspace not found");
        return workspace;
    }
```

Where User.WorkspaceId was a foreign key linking up with WorkspaceId and I could do if checks to see the workspace properties. However, it has come to my attention that a user might have use to be a part of more than one workspace.

So, I've configured a many to many relationship in my database.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkspaceReference>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(bc => new { bc.WorkspaceId, bc.UserId });

            entity.ToTable("workspace_reference");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId)
                .HasName("fk_workspaceref_userid_idx");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.WorkspaceId)
                .HasName("fk_workspaceref_workspaceid_idx");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .HasColumnName("user_id")
                .HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.WorkspaceId)
                .HasColumnName("workspace_id")
                .HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(a => a.WorkspaceReferences)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("fk_workspaceref_userid");


            entity.HasOne(d => d.Workspace)
                .WithMany(c => c.WorkspaceReferences)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.WorkspaceId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("fk_workspaceref_workspaceid");
        });
```

This all shows up well when I do a get requested and I receive the Workspaces.

For instance I would like to do:

```
if(workspace.WorkspaceAllowEdit == 0) { return BadRequest("You're not allowed to edit"); }
```

Is there any way to do a simple check like I did before or would I have to use a list and loop through them each time?

Comment: You need two parameters, the user id (I assume the asp.net logged in user) and the workspace id. Where you store that workspace id is up to you, route parameter, session variable...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman sure, that would be a possibility. However, is there noe way to use like `var users = _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserId);` and then do 
`var workspaces = users.WorkspaceReference.Select(x => x.Workspace)` and select the user workspaces from there?

Comment: Yes, but I'd start the other way around. `_context.Workspace.Where(w => w.WorkspaceReference.Any(r => r.UserId == User.Id)).ToList()`